# An old HP pavilion dv6 does not reproduce sound

Tags: windows-10, audio, sound-card

So here is the thing. An old HP pavilion dv6-1340ss doesnt reproduce any sound.

It seems that the drivers are installed and up to date.

It detects when headphones are connected and disconnected. It detects the hardware in the advanced system settings (control panel).

Windows solutions says there is no problem with the hardware.

I uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers from the HP support page.
I disconnected and reconnected the hardware from the system settings (control panel). 
I tested every single device separately and it does not reproduce the hardware sound. I went and predetermined every single device. I am out of ideas. I don't know where the problem is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See if this helps... https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/a183aa8b-0eac-4566-867a-98d2761a770d/fix-sound-problems

Comment: And this... http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/no-sound-7-tips-fix-audio-issues-windows-10/

Comment: My old HP laptop has problems with sound. I took it to the repair store and they told me it was because it was old. I guess that's the problem with yours.